# Getting Detail Information of process handle

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I have run "`handle.exe -a \Device\0000006c`" on command line where "`\Device\0000006c`" is physical object name of my device for e.g.. Microphone and getting following output:

```
Handle v4.0
Copyright (C) 1997-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

svchost.exe        pid: 864    type: File           770: \Device\0000006c\global
svchost.exe        pid: 864    type: File           ECC: \Device\0000006c\global
svchost.exe        pid: 348    type: File           514: \Device\0000006c\global
svchost.exe        pid: 348    type: File           88C: \Device\0000006c\global
audiodg.exe        pid: 4592   type: File           1C4: \Device\0000006c
audiodg.exe        pid: 4592   type: File           1CC: \Device\0000006c
```

Last two line of output showing that device is being used by audiodg.exe process when audio is being played.

```
audiodg.exe        pid: 4592   type: File           1CC: \Device\0000006c
```

I am able to get that "`1CC`" is handle Hex Address but what is "`\Device\0000006c`" here is it name associated with handle or something else being searched in core of handle.

I am trying to get handle information from this below link

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppFileHandle-03c8ea0b

but not able to get this kind of information for handle

```
DWORD EnumerateFileHandles(ULONG pid)
{
    HINSTANCE hNtDll = LoadLibrary(_T("ntdll.dll"));
assert(hNtDll != NULL);

PFN_NTQUERYSYSTEMINFORMATION NtQuerySystemInformation = 
    (PFN_NTQUERYSYSTEMINFORMATION)GetProcAddress(hNtDll, 
    "NtQuerySystemInformation");
assert(NtQuerySystemInformation != NULL);

PFN_NTQUERYINFORMATIONFILE NtQueryInformationFile = 
    (PFN_NTQUERYINFORMATIONFILE)GetProcAddress(hNtDll, 
    "NtQueryInformationFile");

DWORD nSize = 4096, nReturn;
PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION pSysHandleInfo = (PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)
    HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, nSize);

while (NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemHandleInformation, pSysHandleInfo, 
    nSize, &nReturn) == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
{
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pSysHandleInfo);
    nSize += 4096;
    pSysHandleInfo = (SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION*)HeapAlloc(
        GetProcessHeap(), 0, nSize);
}
DWORD dwFiles = 0;

HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(
    PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
if (hProcess == NULL)
{
    _tprintf(_T("OpenProcess failed w/err 0x%08lx\n"), GetLastError());
    getchar();
    return -1;
}

for (ULONG i = 0; i < pSysHandleInfo->NumberOfHandles; i++)
{
    PSYSTEM_HANDLE pHandle = &(pSysHandleInfo->Handles[i]);

    if(pHandle->ProcessId == pid)
    {
     int a=10;
    }

    if (pHandle->ProcessId == pid && 
        pHandle->ObjectTypeNumber == HANDLE_TYPE_FILE)
    {
        dwFiles++;  // Increase the number of file handles

        // Duplicate the handle in the current process
        HANDLE hCopy;
        if (!DuplicateHandle(hProcess, (HANDLE)pHandle->Handle, 
            GetCurrentProcess(), &hCopy, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, FALSE, 0))
            continue;

        // Retrieve file name information about the file object.
        IO_STATUS_BLOCK ioStatus;
        PFILE_NAME_INFORMATION pNameInfo = (PFILE_NAME_INFORMATION)
            malloc(MAX_PATH * 2 * 2);
        DWORD dwInfoSize = MAX_PATH * 2 * 2;

        if (NtQueryInformationFile(hCopy, &ioStatus, pNameInfo, 
            dwInfoSize, FileNameInformation) == STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
            // Get the file name and print it
            WCHAR wszFileName[MAX_PATH + 1];
            StringCchCopyNW(wszFileName, MAX_PATH + 1, 
                pNameInfo->FileName, /*must be WCHAR*/
                pNameInfo->FileNameLength /*in bytes*/ / 2);

            wprintf(L"0x%x:\t%s\n", pHandle->Handle, wszFileName);
        }
        free(pNameInfo);

        CloseHandle(hCopy);
    }
}

CloseHandle(hProcess);

HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pSysHandleInfo);

// Return the number of file handles in the process
return dwFiles;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
ULONG pid = GetCurrentProcessId();
DWORD dwFiles = EnumerateFileHandles(4592);

_tprintf(TEXT("\r\n"));

// Get file name from file handle using a file mapping object
HANDLE hFile;
hFile = CreateFile(TEXT("test.txt"), GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
    0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    _tprintf(TEXT("CreateFile failed with %d\n"), GetLastError());
    return 0;
}

BYTE bWriteBuffer[] = "0123456789"; 
DWORD dwBytesWritten; 

// Write 11 bytes from the buffer to the file 
if (!WriteFile(hFile,                // File handle 
    bWriteBuffer,                    // Buffer to be write from 
    sizeof(bWriteBuffer),            // Number of bytes to write 
    &dwBytesWritten,                 // Number of bytes that were written 
    NULL))                           // No overlapped structure 
{ 
    // WriteFile returns FALSE because of some error 

    _tprintf(TEXT("Could not write to file w/err 0x%08lx\n"), GetLastError()); 
    CloseHandle(hFile); 
    return 0; 
} 

//GetFileNameFromHandle(hFile);
CloseHandle(hFile);

return 0;
}
```

Any help how handle is programmatically searching for process usage of device by physical device object information.

Comment: That is not possible, the kernel handle table is only accessible to ring 0 code.  Handle recycle attacks are as nasty as they come.  Knowing how to dynamically install a device driver, locating the internal address of an undocumented data structure and keeping it compatible across WIndows versions is are  Mark Russinovich's secrets that he doesn't share.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what specific information you're searching for here? Have you looked into NtQuerySystemInformation() using for example SystemExtendedHandleInformation / SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION_EX?

Comment: You need to give a better description of what you want your program to do and what it's actually doing instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses only **file handle**s of **given process**:

```
if (pHandle->ProcessId == pid && pHandle->ObjectTypeNumber == HANDLE_TYPE_FILE)
```

When you get a handle via SystemHandleInformation, you should check it's type and based on it's type, do something. As you see in your example if handle is file handle, it gets it filename via NtQueryInformationFile. So you should do a similar task on every handle type you want.

Using [NtQueryObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in ntdll, you can get type of a handle. In [this example](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/95774/), every handle of a process used to print some information based on it's type.

Comment: I want to get information about system process is that possible?

Comment: Read my answer carefully. In your code, you only use handles that `pHandle->ProcessId` equals with `pid`. If you remove this `if`, you will get other processes' handles too.